# MySQL join tables and get values that have the same key name

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am trying to select all of the address id's from one table and join the attributes from other tables. I need to join values on tables A and C by entity_id however since the tables have the same key "value" the second join is replacing the value of the first.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
    $query = "SELECT 
        A.parent_id,
        B.value,
        C.value
    FROM customer_address_entity AS A
    LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar AS B 
        ON A.entity_id = B.entity_id
    LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity_text AS C 
        ON A.entity_id = C.entity_id
    LIMIT 100";

    var_dump($query);
```

But I get an array of 4. A.value is being overwritten by C.value

```
array (size=4)
  'parent_id' => string '7' (length=1)
  'entity_id' => string '6' (length=1)
  'value' => string '19 STANDIFORD CT' (length=16)
  'attribute_id' => string '25' (length=2)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the second join is replacing the value of the first"?

Comment: I mean that I should have an array of 5 not 4 but because I am selecting ab.value and ac.value from the tables I only get one key "value" in the array which makes sense because there can only be one unique key in the array but how can I change the key name of each or get the data to come through?

Comment: Ok I see.  Can you provide the code fetching the query results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could alias one column to give it a unique name? i.e.

```
$query = "SELECT 
    A.parent_id,
    B.value,
    C.value as Foobar
FROM customer_address_entity AS A
LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar AS B 
    ON A.entity_id = B.entity_id
LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity_text AS C 
    ON A.entity_id = C.entity_id
LIMIT 100";
...
```

EDIT: There are likely other ways of doing this, but it would be helpful for me to see some example data and possibly some code for the processing of results.

Comment: Thanks!! exactly what I needed!

Comment: Are you able to alias as a value in the row? For example am I able alias C.value as C.title?

Comment: Believe it or not, I don't have a MySQL database handy at the moment, but I _believe_ you could surround the desired alias in quotes to get the table prefix to persist. For example: `C.value as "C.title"`. However, it's important to note that it will likely cause the prefix to come out in **everything**, including the keys in the resulting PHP array structure. Because the prefix wouldn't normally come out in the resulting structure anyway, I don't know if I see a benefit in doing that. Can you elaborate a little more on what you're looking for?

Comment: So your previous example worked but it made me realize that I am now needing to alias B.value as a value from another table. Meaning there are many B and C.values that match the entity_id of A and all of these values need to be Joined to the same array with their corresponding matching title as the key that lives in table_x.  I can post another question to better illustrate what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Here's a link to the new question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34625717/mysql-dyanmic-value-as-alias